# Google Maps KML zIndex property not changing layer display order

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

#### Question

Why doesn't changing the `zIndex` values for my KML layers change which layer is plotted on top?

#### Working example

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/kml#KmlLayerOptions) the `KmlLayerOptionsIterface` has a `zIndex` property.

However, in this example, no matter which layer I set as `zIndex: 1` and `zIndex: 2`, the circles are always displayed on top of the polygons

```
var map;
var kml1 = 'http://www.energy.ca.gov/maps/renewable/BuildingClimateZonesMap.kmz';
var kml2 = 'http://www.energy.ca.gov/maps/renewable/renewable_development.kmz';

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 2
  });
  var kmlLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml1, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map,
    zIndex: 2
  });
  var kmlLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml2, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map,
    zIndex: 1
  });

}
```

Working [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/symbolixau/rmh1soaw/1/)

Should changing the `zIndex` values change which layer is displayed on top?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819949) suggesting this was implemented back in 2015. I would open a new [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) if I was you.

Comment: zIndex works for me with a [simple example (zIndex)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/txr3h4fp/1/) ([example without zIndex](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/txr3h4fp/))

Comment: @geocodezip yes... it does... hmmm. Any ideas why my example is different?

Comment: probably has something to do with the contents of your kmz files.

Comment: @geocodezip yeah looks that way. I'll keep digging using my [github issue](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/163#issuecomment-391881942) and update this question with an answer if I find the reason / solution.

Comment: 2023 update: using two kml layers with lines and icons, icons of higher z level display above all lines of lower z level but sometimes below icons of that level.  So seems flakey. (Icons/lines of each layer created similarly.)